# Why do I get a black cross line when one of the item is out of stock in BigCommerce site?

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

I have a BigCommerce site with a problem. I got a code from online to show a colour name when a customer clicks a swatch image but when one of the colour is out of stock, it displays a black line cross half of the product page. [image: Black Line appears when one of the colour os out of stock.]

Here is the code I found. It works fine with displaying colour name when a swatch is selected but shows black line when one of the colour is out of stock.

```html
<style>
    /* Show the label of a selected color swatch */
    [data-product-attribute="swatch"] {
        position: relative;
    }

    [data-product-attribute="swatch"] .form-option {
        position: static;
    }

    [data-product-attribute="swatch"] .form-option-expanded {
        left: auto;
        top: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

    [data-product-attribute="swatch"] .form-radio:checked+.form-option .form-option-variant:after {
        content: attr(title);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 300px;
        
    }
</style>
```

If anyone knows the solution to this problem, I would really appreciate if you could share it with me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML code please? Can you simulate the issue with the code you attached in jsfiddle and send a URL for testing?

Comment: @NickHolden Here is the link to jsfiddle for my site. https://jsfiddle.net/MontyVan/yrax5968/3/

Comment: That grey bar is what's used to cross unavailable products. When you removed the `position: relative` from the `.form-option` you made it use the closest `position: relative` to position itself. You can either remove the bar, or find a different solution for the name.

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina If I take .form-option out, the black line becomes smaller but the colour name breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from here, specifically from the `unavailable` class:

```
<label class="form-option form-option-swatch unavailable" for="attribute_swatch_1392" data-product-attribute-value="1392">
```

[image: See here]

This is originating from the following CSS file:

```
<link data-stencil-stylesheet="" href="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-711f1/stencil/ebdb0640-a75d-0138-85b8-0242ac11000f/e/7774b960-acd3-0138-768f-0242ac110009/css/theme-a97afbc0-a909-0138-ccda-0242ac110011.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you for the information but I am having a problem locating the CSS file you have mentioned in the backend of the site...

Comment: That file is an aggregation of all CSS files from your project. The actual class lives in the `_forms.scss` file: https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/4e67c81ba03189123e943bf2e54059ebb86499d3/assets/scss/components/citadel/forms/_forms.scss#L361-L383